# how to pass unsigned int reference to from python to C++ using swig?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am using swig, which is wrapping one of my C++ function:

```
get(unsigned int a, unsigned int &b);
```

but i am failing to call this function from python, the error i get is TypeError that it should be unsigned int&

how call to this function from python ? should i add something special to the .i file ?

Comment: Tell us more about your function. Does it return anything? Is the reference argument used only for output, or for input as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes，you should add typemaps.

## example:

- export.i:
  %module my_mod
  %include "typemaps.i"
  %apply unsigned int &OUTPUT {unsigned int&};    **//this map you output**
  %include "export.h"
- export.h
  void get(unsigned int a, unsigned int& b);
- test
  print(my_mod.get(10))